# Columns in column order, equal height, with dynamic content

Tags: css

I sat all day trying to beat this thing. It seems so childishly simple, but I have seemed to hit a brick wall.
These are the criteria:

- Two columns
- To be read in a **column** order
- Vertical align top
- Each item has a border top, and a border bottom
- The selected item has a different color of the borders
- The content, number of rows and height are unknown; it can be 3 items, it can be 17 items
- **One div** to contain all items, not two
- No JS, no jQuery

```
<ul>
  <li>Item 1</li>
  <li>Item 2</li>
  <li>Item 3</li>
  <li>Item 4</li>
  <li>Item 5</li>
  <li>Item 6</li>
  <li>Item 7</li>
</ul>
```

My goal:

```
---------  ---------
Item 1     Item 5
---------  ---------
Item 2     Item 6
---------  ---------
Item 3     Item 7
---------  ---------
Item 4
---------
```

Here is what I got: https://codepen.io/martinlex/pen/bZgmvV?editors=1100

My issues:

1. I have double borders everywhere, except from the top items and the bottom items. The border width must be 1px everywhere.
2. The columns solution: the borders disappears randomly from the top and bottom.
3. The grid solution: you need to know the exact number of rows, when the auto-flow is column.
4. Can flexbox handle this?

Comment: `column-count:2` + `column-fill:balance` was suppose to be the way for such a layout, but it was drop from specification and back  is still partially supported, if you are willing to test it through the browsers you want to support : https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aMpPVZ  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Columns/Using_multi-column_layouts

Comment: The columns solution was my first take on this. Actually, it works great cross-browser, but the borders won't work. They go missing out in some places, in your example on item 7.

Comment: for the borders, use either top or bottom then add a shadow to cover previous or next border's item. (pen updated) ;)

Comment: `.item i{
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 lightgrey;/* update*/
  padding: 8px;
}

.selected {
  box-shadow: 0 -1px 0 red;/* update*/
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  position: relative;/* update*/
}`  https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aMpPVZ

Comment: The interesting concept of mixing border and box-shadow generates this: https://pasteboard.co/I4ia1zW.png. All good, but it breaks on item 8 where the top border is missing.

Comment: Okay, maybe you should rethink the margin:-0.5px. Screen is drawn pixel per pixel ;) . Box-shadow can also be inset

Comment: Here is what I mean about margin and inset shadow https://codepen.io/gc-nomade/pen/aMJqpw

Answer (score 1):

Whenever you use a list, there is always going to be some margin between `li` items by default. Your solution works perfectly fine with grid, just simply remove the default margin by adding `margin: -0.5px` to your `.item` class.

```css
.list {
  display: grid;
  grid-column-gap: 16px;
  grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
  grid-template-rows: repeat(7, auto);
  grid-auto-flow: column;
}

.item {
  border-bottom: 1px solid lightgrey;
  border-top: 1px solid lightgrey;
  padding: 8px;
  margin: -0.5px;
  list-style: none;
}

.selected {
  border-top: 1px solid red;
  border-bottom: 1px solid red;
  z-index: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul class="list">
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 1</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 2</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 3</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 4</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 5</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 6</li>
  <li class="item selected">Asdfghjkl 7</li>
  <li class="item selected">Asdfghjkl 8</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 9</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 10</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 11</li>
  <li class="item selected">Asdfghjkl 12</li>
  <li class="item">Asdfghjkl 13</li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Thanks Nick, nice idea, but there is still double border in three random places. Between 2-3, 5-6 and 9-10... Using Chrome on Mac.

Comment: Can you include a picture? I just ran it on my Macbook in Chrome and it worked the same as my Windows PC.

Comment: Sure! https://pasteboard.co/I4dQGPh.png Also you can see item 8 (selected) is broken, it should have a red bottom border.

Comment: The top border of the following element is overlapping the bottom border of the previous element, so you can fix that by adding `z-index: 1` to the `.selected` class. This will make it so the red border is always on top of the gray border.

Comment: Regarding the double borders in your image: they seem completely random and I could not replicate those results on my Windows PC, Macbook, or my girlfriend's Mac PC. That's very bizarre behavior. I've removed some excess code that you originally had but was not being used. Hopefully this solves the problem you are facing.

Comment: I was thinking, there is no such thing as a half pixel. Maybe you have retina displays, so it looks better on your end?

Comment: I know it doesn't exactly make sense to have fractional pixels, and they never used to be supported by any browser years ago. Believe it or not, but fractional pixels are actually supported now. The behavior from browser to browser varies, as they round differently. It very well could be the screen differences or even browser version that is causing the issue on your end.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 1: This is a screenshot with Flexbox solution:
https://pasteboard.co/I4hDGRM.png

```
display: flex;
flex-direction: column;
flex-flow: column wrap;
height: 340px; /* NEEDS HEIGHT */
```

It is exactly what I want. **However:** it needs a `height` value for the list. I don't have it, it will be different depending on content.

Answer (score 0):

UPDATE 2: This is a screenshot with Css grid solution: https://pasteboard.co/I4hKqRb.png

```
display: grid;
grid-column-gap: 16px;
grid-template-columns: repeat(2, 1fr);
grid-template-rows: repeat(7, auto); /* CANNOT SET 7 AS A MAGIC NUMBER */
grid-auto-flow: column;
```

Also, this is again what I want. But it needs a `grid-template-rows` value, which I don't have, for the same reason as above.